# Dual ISP/Network, Force DHCP Clients to One?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, wan

I've got two ISPs, connected to their own respective routers running on their own subnets. Set up routes on both so I can connect to the resources on either. The [ASUS RT‑AC66U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTAC66U/) is set to dual WAN, with cable modem in WAN and secondary WAN set to LAN 1 wired to the [ASUS N12D1](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTN12_D1/).

What I’m curious of, can I set it up so regardless of which Wi-Fi one connects to, it will default any DHCP clients to one specific router/ISP

I’m aiming at keeping a few devices using the cable modem for PC gaming, PS4 and PS3 while everything else is sent to the DSL.

Comment: If you only have a handful of known devices, why don't you just assign them IP addresses manually and then disable the DHCP for the cable?

Comment: If you can configure DHCP to give out a default gateway IP other than the routers, you could set the DHCP scope on both routers to cover a different range but give out the same default gateway. For example, Router A gives out IP's in range 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.50 with /24 range and 192.168.0.1 as default gateway. Router B gives out IP's in range 192.168.0.51 - 192.168.0.100 range  with /24 mask and 192.168.0.1 as default gateway.

Comment: I originally had it setup where both were on the same subnet (192.168.192.0/24), DHCP running on the AC66u but sending out the other gateway (192.168.192.2). This worked when I had an old Dell TrueMobile 2300 running Tomato, but when I was forced to upgrade (lightning came in and ruined most of my network, whole different story there) these two ASUS will not play nicely in the same exact setup (web pages refuse to load, I think its a DNS issue but can't suss out how/where/why).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way.

Using an online Subnet calculator and reading about subnets, I changed from a 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.254.0, each router has their own range of IP addresses but both designate the DSL router as the assigned gateway. Devices I don't want to reach the DSL I put in the cable's router gateway IP address manually.

So any new device connecting to any of the WiFi networks will automatically be on the DSL.